# CUDA: efficient method for generating random integers in a fixed range without repeats?

Tags: cuda, random

The problem is getting an array of N integers (with N=1024 or more) randomly extracted WITHOUT REPEATS from a uniform distribution in the range [0, N-1]. 
In other words, randomly shuffling an array v of N integers, where v[i] = i, with i=0, ..., N-1.

I have no particular constraints except that I am writing a CUDA application, thus I need to place this array in device global memory.

Gratefully accepted solutions could make use either of library functions (such as Thrust or cuRAND) or custom kernels.

Thank you.

Comment: If you already know about Thrust and cuRAND, why don't you start writing the code with them?

Comment: Do you need only one of these arrays? What is a likely maximum N?

Comment: You can easily write the code yourself using a standard algorithm. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @njuffa: The standard algorithm is serial, not parallel.

Comment: @Domi: That's what I am trying to do and I will post the code if I succeed in this, but as it seems to be a general problem I was wondering if anyone was aware of particular implementations in CUDA or even just some ideas...

Comment: At [How to generate random permutations with CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653995/how-to-generate-random-permutations-with-cuda), there is a discussion on how parallelizing the Fisher-Yates algorithm.

Comment: @RogerDahl: I need to compute such an array at every iteration of a genetic algorithm which runs for hundreds of iterations, thus I would like to compute it on the device to avoid repeated memory transfers and to explore the possibility of parallelizing this operation... N is the size of the population of the genetic algorithm, I think it will be of the order of about 1024-4096(-8192) but I do not know exactly yet, it depends on other criteria... Thank you.

Comment: @JackOLantern: thanks for the suggestion, I had not found that question. It is very useful, except that the implementation of the function that swaps two locations in an atomic way does not seem so obvious to me (I am thinking about this issue). I also found a discussion on random shuffling at [Array shuffle in CUDA?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/483761/array-shuffle-in-cuda-/) where some other strategies are suggested. Among these ones, a simple one (I don't know how accurate) is to assign a random number to each element as a key and then sort the array by key.